# Slim - pass raw data string to request body

Tags: php, slim

I'm performing a unit test for my API endpoints in Slim. This is what I used to pass data to the endpoint:

```
$requestData = [
    'field1' => 123,
    'field2' => 4567,
    ....
]    
$request->withParsedBody($requestData);
```

Now need to test the endpoint with XML or JSON string like below -

```
    $requestData = '<xml>
           <appid><![CDATA[app123]]></appid>
           <device_info><![CDATA[test-device-5678]]></device_info>
           ....
           </xml>';
    $request->withParsedBody($requestData);
```

The problem is that withParsedBody() only accepts array or object. So my question is: what's the proper way to pass raw data string to the request?

Comment: you can try `$json = json_encode($string)` than `json_decode($json,true)` for array

Comment: Unfortunately, the endpoint is expecting XML strings and will throw error when the input is not XML strings. So I'll have to pass original string to test it.

Comment: well you can do `$request->getBody()->write("string");`

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm! Just a note - I need to call  $request->reparseBody(); after the write() so that the new string will be parsed in the request object.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer based on Dusan's comments.

```
        $request->getBody()->write($requestData);
        $request->reparseBody();
```

The reparseBody() call will force the request object to parse the new content again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it would be better

```
$requestData = '<xml>
           <appid><![CDATA[app123]]></appid>
           <device_info><![CDATA[test-device-5678]]></device_info>
           ....
           </xml>';

$streamFactory = new \Zend\Diactoros\StreamFactory();
$stream = $streamFactory->createStream($requestData);

$request->withBody($stream);

echo (string) $request->getBody();
```